# How to convert date strings from different TimeZones to Date object in one TimeZone

Tags: java, date, timezone

Im working on an RSS reader software. I get items with their pubDate (publish date) values as string, convert them to Date object, and put them to my DB. However, when I check my DB, I saw some interesting values such as the date of tomorrow.

I research this situation and found that it is about time zone value Z. For example when I get "Mon, 26 May 2014 21:24:29 -0500", it becomes "2014-05-27 05:24:29", the next day !

All I want is to get dates in any timezone and convert them to date in common timezone, such as my country's.

Here is my code :

```
 public static String convert(String datestr) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    Date date = formatter.parse(datestr);

    SimpleDateFormat resultFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return  resultFormatter.format(date);
}
```

And I use the method like that :

```
 System.out.println(convert("Mon, 26 May 2014 21:24:29 -0500"));
```

The output is  : 2014-05-27 05:24:29

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the current date of your system then change the timezone to -5:00 and check it again.

Comment: but the input is not always -0500, it may be -0300,+500 etc too.. I want to take them all, then convert them to my own timezone

Comment: that's why it's converted to your timezone. Isn't it? What do you need? do you want to extract the timezone info from the input string as well.

Comment: Assume that today is 26 may 2014 21:00. The rss source puts a date "Mon, 26 May 2014 21:24:29 -0500". My program gets it an checks if it is a new element or not. It converts the date and get 2014-05-27 05:24:29, but today is still 26 May 2014 not 27. I want to get the exact value of the date in my timezone. Maybe the RSS source is wrong..

Comment: Have you tried my second solution?

Comment: Thanks for your kindly advice, but I think we need the zzz info. Because I need the converted version of the given date, not the exact same date.

Comment: I you have mixed all the thinks. Let me explain it again **date in one timezone can be different from your timezone**. You want to consider the timezone and want to convert it into your timezone as well and looking for same date as well. Think about it again. Isn't it your program doing as expected?

Comment: So Isn't it strange for you ? I get a "publish date" of news in different TZ, convert it to my TZ and the result date is tomorrow  :)

Comment: no its not, what the time there? It's 28 May 3:37 A.M here in India UTC+5:30.

Comment: it is 28 may 01:12 here in Turkey. In other word, if I convert your time to my zone, I excepct to see 28 may 01:12. If I see "29" may, it makes things strange :)

Comment: Think about the time and date 2 hours back

Comment: I re create screnario : I convert your time to my zone, I expect to see 28 may 01:12 and I see 29 may 09:12. How can it be a FUTURE time ? How can it be LARGER than current date ? The rss source gives me this result. I know the 00:00 point and day changing situation.

Comment: Read [How Time Zones Work](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html). It's time to sleep. Good night.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't set a time zone, it's using your system's default.

Set a specific [IANA time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
SimpleDateFormat resultFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
resultFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
return resultFormatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected. The date is converted as per your system's timezone.

Check the UTC offset of your system and replace it in the sample date string and look at the output.

---

For e.g: India is UTC+5:30

```
String datestr="Mon, 26 May 2014 21:24:29 +0530";
```

output:

```
2014-05-26 21:24:29
```

---

#### Alternate solution

If you don't want to consider the timezone of the input date string then simply truncate this information and remove `zzz` from pattern as well as shown in below code:

```
String datestr = "Mon, 26 May 2014 21:24:29 -0530";
datestr = datestr.replaceAll("\\s[-+](\\d+)$", ""); // truncate the timezone info if not needed

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // remove zzz from the pattern
Date date = formatter.parse(datestr);

SimpleDateFormat resultFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(resultFormatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you passed a Date with timezone, but given a wrong format. If you are passing timezone like "-0500" you should rather use:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```

Remember that the system will always display the date using the current, default timezone (TimeZone.getDefault()) unless you override it by:

```
resultFormatter.setTimeZone(...)
```

Comment: why use `setTimeZone()` if OP is looking for default one only as OP's country?

Comment: You`re right. Better practice is to have JVM properly configured rather than manually override timezone each call.